# Как правильно передать массивы в шаблон?

Tags: twig, шаблонизаторы

Пользуюсь шаблонизатором Twig. И вот такая ситуация:
В таблице например,есть 2 человека.У них имя-одинаковые,а фамилий-разные:
иван-иванов
иван-андреев
вася-попов
вася-рожков
............
И у меня таблица,первом столбце имя,а во втором-фамилий.Хотелось бы вроде такого сделать:

```
 <table>
 <tr><th><Name></th><th>Family</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Иван</td><td>Иванов<hr>Андреев</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Вася</td><td>попов<hr>Рожков</td></tr>
 </table>
```

То есть фамилий,разделить через тэг  `<hr>`.
Попробовал так печатать через цикл:

```
     {% for arru in arr %}  
<tr><td> {{ arru }}  </td></tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

Но незнаю как впихнуть фамилий..Как я понимаю им тоже цикл нужен??? Подскажите плиз..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr><th><Name></th><th>Family</th></tr>
{% for arru in arr %}  
    <tr><td>{{ arru.first }}</td><td>{{ arru.last }}</td></tr> 
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Соответственно передавать `arru` нужно примерно так:

```
$template->render(
    array('arru' => array(
        array('first' => 'Иван', 'last' => 'Иванов'),
        array('first' => 'Вася', 'last' => 'попов')
    ))
);
```

Надеюсь что понятно объявнил